# php mysql filtered pagination results doesn't work on next pages

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

Good day. I need your expert input. I've been working on with pagination with filtered results from mysql.

The filtered results only works on the first page. Clicking on the next or succeeding pages, i am getting below errors and it showing all the data in the database as well.

> Notice: Undefined index: search Notice: Undefined index: position
>   Notice: Undefined index: dept Notice: Undefined index: bldg
>   and so on...

i wonder what i could be missing...

### here is the updated code:

```
<?php
    include('include/connect.php'); 

    $tableName="employee";      
    $targetpage = "searchresults.php";  
    $limit = 5; 


    $search = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['search']);
    $position = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['position']);
    $dept = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['dept']);
    $bldg = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['bldg']);

    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM $tableName WHERE name like '%{$search}%' AND position like '%{$position}%' AND dept like '%{$dept}%' AND bldg like '%{$bldg}%'";
    $total_pages = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
    $total_pages = $total_pages['num'];

    $stages = 3;



    //  $page = mysql_escape_string($_GET['page']);


    $page = isset($_GET['page']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['page']) : 0;



    if($page){          
        $start = ($page - 1) * $limit; 
    }else {
        $start = 0; 
    }

    // Get page data

    $query1 = "SELECT * FROM $tableName WHERE ads like '%{$search}%' AND position like '%{$position}%' AND dept like '%{$dept}%' AND bldg like '%{$bldg}%' ORDER BY dateposted DESC LIMIT $start, $limit";
    $result = mysql_query($query1);

    // Initial page num setup
    if ($page == 0){$page = 1;}
    $prev = $page - 1;  
    $next = $page + 1;                          
    $lastpage = ceil($total_pages/$limit);      
    $LastPagem1 = $lastpage - 1;                    

    $paginate = '';
    if($lastpage > 1)
    {   




        $paginate .= "<div class='paginate'>";
        // Previous
        if ($page > 1){
            $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$prev'>previous</a>";
        }else{
            $paginate.= "<span class='disabled'>previous</span>";   }



        // Pages    
        if ($lastpage < 7 + ($stages * 2))  // Not enough pages to breaking it up
        {   
            for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
            {
                if ($counter == $page){
                    $paginate.= "<span class='current'>$counter</span>";
                }else{
                    $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$counter'>$counter</a>";}                    
            }
        }
        elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($stages * 2))   // Enough pages to hide a few?
        {
            // Beginning only hide later pages
            if($page < 1 + ($stages * 2))       
            {
                for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($stages * 2); $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page){
                        $paginate.= "<span class='current'>$counter</span>";
                    }else{
                        $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$counter'>$counter</a>";}                    
                }
                $paginate.= "...";
                $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$LastPagem1&search=$search&position=$position&dept=$dept&‌​bldg=$bldg''>$LastPagem1</a>";
                $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$lastpage'>$lastpage</a>";       
            }
            // Middle hide some front and some back
            elseif($lastpage - ($stages * 2) > $page && $page > ($stages * 2))
            {
                $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=1'>1</a>";
                $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=2'>2</a>";
                $paginate.= "...";
                for ($counter = $page - $stages; $counter <= $page + $stages; $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page){
                        $paginate.= "<span class='current'>$counter</span>";
                    }else{
                        $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$counter'>$counter</a>";}                    
                }
                $paginate.= "...";
                $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$LastPagem1&search=$search&position=$position&dept=$dept&‌​bldg=$bldg'>$LastPagem1</a>";
                $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$lastpage'>$lastpage</a>";       
            }
            // End only hide early pages
            else
            {
                $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=1'>1</a>";
                $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=2'>2</a>";
                $paginate.= "...";
                for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($stages * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page){
                        $paginate.= "<span class='current'>$counter</span>";
                    }else{
                        $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$counter'>$counter</a>";}                    
                }
            }
        }

                // Next
        if ($page < $counter - 1){ 
            $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$next'>next</a>";
        }else{
            $paginate.= "<span class='disabled'>next</span>";
            }

        $paginate.= "</div>";       


}
 echo $total_pages.' Results';
 // pagination
 echo $paginate;

?>

<ul>

<?php 

        echo "<table id='t01' border='5' style='width:100%' align='center'>";

                echo "<tr>";                                 
                    echo "<th>NAME</th>";
            echo "<th>CONTACT</th>";
            echo "<th>DEPT</th>";
            echo "<th>BLDG</th>";   
            echo "<th>POSITION</th>";   
                    echo "<th>COMMENT</th>";

                echo "</tr>";




        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {

        // echo '<li>'.$row['user'].'</li>';

        echo "<tr>";                    

                    echo "<td>" . $row['user'] . "</td>";

            echo "<td>" . $row['contact'] . "</td>";

            echo "<td>" . $row['dept'] . "</td>";   

            echo "<td>" . $row['bldg'] . "</td>";

            echo "<td>" . $row['position'] . "</td>";   

                    echo "<td>" . $row['comment'] . "</td>";


                echo "</tr>";







        }





    ?>
```

Comment: DO NOT USE mysql_* . It is removed in PHP7 .

Comment: it seems i need to rewrite all the codes again?

Comment: To make your application  better yes. You can use PDO/Mysqli instead.

Comment: Pass your filter parameter when you click on pagination link. than you read the filter value using `$_REQUEST` so that it will work in get and post method

Comment: how will i do that? sorry i am new to programming. and where do i insert it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are creating you pagination links you are not adding the query parameters in the created links that is the reason that when you go to the next page the parameters are missing.

So wherever you create a pagination link like this

`$paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$LastPagem1'>$LastPagem1</a>";`

along with the pagenum add the parameters that were searched for. E.g (adding the search item)

`$paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$LastPagem1&search=$search'>$LastPagem1</a>";`

Along with that you seem to be getting data from the $_POST variable, now when you add your parameters on the link you will have to get them through $_GET
like

`$_GET['search']` and so on...

And assuming that the first time the search is made, it is sent using a `method="post"` on the form, you can change that as well to be `method="get"` if that suits your use case.

Update:

**You need to add the query parameters to all of the links and not just at one place.**

So what you can do first is create a variable that has all of your query parameters already concatenated

`$params = "&search=$search&position=$position&dept=$dept&‌​bldg=$bldg";`

Then wherever you have your code where you write something like

`<a href='$targetpage?page=$LastPagem1'>`

Add the params variable there as well like :

`<a href='$targetpage?page=$LastPagem1{$params}'>`

Remember this needs to be done at all the places in your code where you pass `?page=` or for testing check only the link that you updated.

Comment: ohh ok, will try again

Comment: it just the same even if ive changed the form method to get  as well

Comment: $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$LastPagem1&search=$search&position=$position&dept=$dept&bldg=$bldg'>$LastPagem1</a>";

Comment: i also change the form method from post to get. but to no avail

Comment: @alex You need to update all of your links to have the search parameters. I have updated the answer for you.

Comment: @alex Thanks for your kind words :)